# How to open a document using an application launched via NSTask?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstask

I've grown tired of the built-in `open` Mac OS X command, mostly because it runs programs with your actual user ID instead of the effective user ID; this results in the fact `sudo open Foo` opens Foo with its associated application with your account instead of the `root` account, and it annoys me. So I decided to make some kind of replacement.

So far I've been successful: I can open any program under the `open -a` or `open -b` fashion, and support optionally waiting. I'm using `NSTask` for that purpose.

However, I'd like to be able to open documents too. As far as I can see, you need to use `NSWorkspace` for that, but using `NSWorkspace` to launch programs results in them being launched with your account's credentials instead of your command line program's credentials. Which is precisely what the default `open` tool does, and precisely what I don't want.

So, how can I have a program request that another program opens a document without using `NSWorkspace`? From the `NSTask` object, I can have the process ID, but that's about it.

Comment: What you describe would be an extreme security risk. Running a GUI app as root is not a good idea at all. Why do you want to do this? There is probably a better way.

Comment: @Rob Keniger: My goal is to have an `open`-like program that runs programs under `root` if I `sudo open` them, instead of having to do `sudo /full/application/path/Contents/MacOS/program`. I know the risks of running programs as `root`, and I want to do it for myself. There is no redistribution planned nor will be any production environment depending on it. For instance, sometimes I just want information from the Activity Monitor that can only be gathered if it's run as `root` (like open files & ports of daemons). It's not like I want to run the Finder or Safari as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will do the trick:

```
- (void)openFile:(NSString *)filePath withTask:(NSTask *)task {
    int pid = [task processIdentifier];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *target = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithDescriptorType:typeKernelProcessID bytes:&pid length:sizeof(pid)];

    const char *urlUTF8 = [[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] absoluteString] UTF8String];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *urlDescriptor = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithDescriptorType:typeFileURL bytes:urlUTF8 length:strlen(urlUTF8)];

    NSAppleEventDescriptor *event = [NSAppleEventDescriptor appleEventWithEventClass:kEventParamAppleEvent eventID:kAEOpen targetDescriptor:target returnID:kAutoGenerateReturnID transactionID:kAnyTransactionID];
    [event setParamDescriptor:urlDescriptor forKeyword:keyDirectObject];

    OSStatus err = AESendMessage([event aeDesc], NULL, kAENoReply | kAENeverInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout);

    if (err != noErr) {
        // Error handling goes here
    }

    // Activate the application

    event = [NSAppleEventDescriptor appleEventWithEventClass:kAEMiscStandards eventID:kAEActivate targetDescriptor:target returnID:kAutoGenerateReturnID transactionID:kAnyTransactionID];
    err = AESendMessage([event aeDesc], NULL, kAENoReply | kAENeverInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout); 
}
```

> You may have to launch the application
>   using an `NSTask` and then send it the
>   appropriate open Apple Event.
>
> Actually, can you launch using an
>   `NSTask` and then open the file via
>   `NSWorkspace` once you know it's
>   running? Or does that launch a new
>   instance of the application under your
>   user?
>
> Original reply:
>
> > Does
> >
> > `open -a SomeApplication SomeFile`
> >
> > work?

Comment: I feel you did not quite read the question. :/ `open -a SomeApp SomeFile` will open the desired file in the desired application, but `sudo open -a SomeApp SomeFile` won't run it with the `root` account, which is my grief against the `open` program, and the reason I'm writing a replacement.

Comment: Oh, under the open -a *fashion*. I misread that part. Let me edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Yes, opening the document from NSWorkspace once the application runs with the `root` account will open the document into it; however, there are cases in which it will fail (like if there was another instance of the opened application running under the regular user account). Apple Events might be the way to go; do you have any useful documentation link for that? `initWithEventClass:eventID:targetDescriptor:returnID:transactionID:` scares me.

Comment: You can get an AE descriptor for your app given the process ID easily enough. I can try to wrangle up some code if you still need it.

Comment: (And you're definitely right about the NSWorkspace stuff not working the way you want it to when you have multiple instances open.)

Comment: Oh damn! I'm sorry dude, I didn't notice you edited your answer. Don't forget to include @username in your comments if you want people to be notified! I'll try that and accept your answer if it works. Just let me remember what I wanted this for...

Comment: Thanks! It works. Though, you need to link against the Carbon framework to get the `kEventParamAppleEvent` constant.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about that. +1